# Perl - lookahead assertion

Tags: perl

I'm trying to describe a perl script for this purpose:

```
a = ~b & ~c;  ==> a = (~b) & (~c);
a = ~b & (~c); ==> a = (~b) & (~c);
```

So I used lookahead assertions to insert parenthesis like this. Here is the test code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5 -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
my @lines;

@lines =  (
  "assign a = ~b & ~c;",
  "assign a = (~b) & (~c);",
  "assign a = ( ~b  & ~c );", 
  "assign a =  (b  & ~c );"
);

foreach $line (@lines) {
  print "   $line\n";
  $line =~ s/(?!\(\s*)~\w+(?!\s*\))/\($&\)/g;
  print ">> $line\n\n";
}
```

It looks working with above examples.  However, it's not working with this.

```
   assign a = ~b & ~c;
>> assign a = (~b) & (~c);     <== OK

   assign a = (~b) & (~c);
>> assign a = (~b) & (~c);     <== OK

   assign a = ( ~b  & ~c);
>> assign a = ( (~b)  & ~c);   <== X. I want ( (~b)  & (~c));

   assign a = ( ~b  & ~c );
>> assign a = ( (~b)  & ~c );  <== X. I want ( (~b)  & (~c) );
```

Would you let me know how to fix the script?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal of using lookahead and lookbehind assertions doesn't really get you anything.  Breaking up the code into two steps makes it easier in my opinion.  One step to capture variables prefixed by ~, and the second part to see if they're surrounded by balanced parenthesis.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp(my $src = <DATA>);
    chomp(my $test = <DATA>);

    $src =~ s{([(]?~\w+[)]?)}{
        my $str = $1;
        $str =~ /^\(.*\)$/ ? $str : "($str)";
    }eg;

    print "test    $test\n";
    print $src eq $test ? '  ok    ' : '  FAIL! ';
    print "$src\n";
}

__DATA__
Test:
a = ~b & ~c;
a = (~b) & (~c);
Test:
a = (~b) & (~c);
a = (~b) & (~c);
Test:
a = ( ~b  & ~c);
a = ( (~b)  & (~c));
Test:
a = ( ~b  & ~c );
a = ( (~b)  & (~c) );
```

results:

```
test    a = (~b) & (~c);
  ok    a = (~b) & (~c);
test    a = (~b) & (~c);
  ok    a = (~b) & (~c);
test    a = ( (~b)  & (~c));
  ok    a = ( (~b)  & (~c));
test    a = ( (~b)  & (~c) );
  ok    a = ( (~b)  & (~c) );
```

Comment: Hmm. A bit of an icky way to post your input. Completely different from the OP's and it has `Test:` in lines that are ignored.

Comment: @Borodin To me, the input itself is kinda icky.  Was just searching for a way to make it easier to read, and spacing between the pairs seemed to work best.  Especially since it didn't require any additional parsing on my part to get the test data ready for use.  As for it not being how the OP did it, I like to encourage people to put their test data with expected results in the <DATA> section, especially for scripts like this.

Comment: Okay then I understand, but I don't think your last sentence is appropriate here. I think you should copy the input data definition (i.e. the `@lines` assignment) and show the output as a demonstration that you have run your solution, and that it matches what the OP said he wanted. Pairing test data with an expected result is spot on in the real world, but on SO you shouldn't be providing either, and copying and interleaving what was provided makes it harder to verify against the *real* benchmark. Thanks for making me think, and of course your ideas may differ :)

Comment: @Borodin I might've considered using his definition of test data instead of modeling what I think is a better testing setup, but he didn't have any `my @lines` definition when I composed my answer.  Anyway, thank you for challenging my assumptions as well, and forcing me to occasionally justify my reasoning.  One of the reasons why I'm spending time on here now is to refresh my skills and have my potentially outdated talents reworked some.  Therefore, appreciate the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do what you're asking using a single regular expression.

The problem is that there is no way to count the number of nested parentheses without writing a recursive regex pattern, so at the end of `~c` simple regex cannot know whether how many parentheses are needed to close the expression.

This *is* possible with a more complex regex, but it would also be much easier to tokenize the string in a Perl loop.

Do you have to deal with stuff like `a & ~b & c | (d | ~e & f)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one regex, here it is;  
`$line =~ s/(?|([^\(])(~\w+)(.)|(.)(~\w+)([^\)]))/$1\($2\)$3/g;`

Your reqex wasn't doing what you thought.

```
$line =~ s/(?!\(\s*)~\w+(?!\s*\))/\($&\)/g;
```

the first part "(?!(\s*)~" will never match.  Remember lookaheads and lookbehinds are zero width assertions.  I like to think of them as matching the space in between the letters. (?!(\s*)~ means, that you want to match a "~" character, but in the space right before the "~"character, you want to lookahead and make sure you dont see a "(" and spaces.  Well, if you are in the space right before a "~", you"ll never see a "(".  And if your at a "(", the negative look ahead might fail to match (like you want) but you'd have never matched the "~" anyway.

You are trying to match if the character before is not a "(" AND the char after is not a ")".  But what you want is to match if the character before is not a "(" OR the char after is not a ")".  So you need a conditional branch, one to match if there is no "(" in front, and one to match if there is no ")" behind.

I used a condition branch, the (?| tells the engine to store the captured submatches like this;
    `(?|([^\\(])(~\w+)(.)|(.)(~\w+)([^\\)]))`
           `$1   $2  $3 |$1    $2   $3`
instead of this
    `([^\\(])(~\w+)(.)|(.)(~\w+)([^\\)]))`
      `$1      $2  $3 |$4   $5     $6`
I used (.) to make the ~\w part always $2, then just put a "(" ")" around the $2 in the output

my output
   assign a = ~b & ~c;

> > assign a = (~b) & (~c);

assign a = (~b) & (~c);

> > assign a = (~b) & (~c);

assign a = ( ~b  & ~c );

> > assign a = ( (~b)  & (~c) );

assign a =  (~b  & ~c );

> > assign a =  ((~b)  & (~c) );

assign a = ( ~b  & ~c );

> > assign a = ( (~b)  & (~c) );

assign a = ( ~b  & ~c);

> > assign a = ( (~b)  & (~c));

Comment: Please as a /x modifier and make your regex easier for us to read. Thanks!